# Cannot reproduce spectral clustering results on another machine

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn

When I use the function of'`affinity='precomputed`', `assign_labels='discretize'` and `random_state=0` have been defined, but the clustering results on another computer are still different, using '`kmeans`' and the same random_state are still Not the same, how do can I make the clustering results of different devices the same?
here is my code:

```
sc = SpectralClustering(cluster_number, affinity='precomputed', assign_labels='discretize', random_state=0)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Weird!  If you provide a `numpy.random.RandomState` instance as described at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state does it wrk then?